# How to return the max value of a group of rows that are grouped by date

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate

So I need to find the max number of zCumuEnrolled and return the value only once. This is what I have so far.

```
SELECT Distinct(MAX(zCumuEnrolled)) as total, 
       DateName(mm,zDate) as date, 
       DatePart(yyyy,zDate) as date2
FROM vRecruitment  
Where zDate Between '2010-05-01' AND '2010-05-30' 
GROUP BY zDate
```

When I do this I get:

```
total|Date|Date2
    0| May|2010
    1| May|2010
```

All I really want is just to return the record with total = 1. Any advice would be much appreciated!!! Thanks in advance!

Comment: `distinct` is **not** a function. You don't apply it to a single column, it is applied to all column in the select list!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You grouping by full date, for correct result you need to group by month and year.
Set all dates to XXXX-XX-01 format and then group by this expression.

`dateadd(day, - datePart(day, zDate) + 1, zDate)`

Try next code

```
SELECT 
    MAX(zCumuEnrolled) as total,
    DateName(mm, d) as date1,
    DatePart(yyyy, d) as date2
FROM 
    (select *, dateadd(day, - datePart(day, zDate) + 1, zDate) as d from vRecruitment) t
Where 
    zDate Between '2010-05-01' AND '2010-05-30' 
GROUP BY 
    d
```

This works well if you want to get max value by monthes

Comment: This works for me! I noticed that if I do any time more than a month then it wouldn't work but I don't care about that. I was just randomly testing the code! Thanks again!!!

Comment: +1. There's also a "shortcut" for `DATEPART(DAY, …)`, called `DAY(…)`. Also, a date can be truncated to the month like this: `DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, dateColumn), 0)`.

Answer (score 1):

Grouping by zDate causes the result to have a record for each distinct value of zDate; if you want the maximum over the whole range of dates, eliminate the GROUP BY clause.  (And why do you need Max to be Distinct?)

Comment: I need distinct because when I select max I can get multiple rows, the cumulative enrolled doesn't always change day to day. Since I'm converting the query results into xml I can only have one row returned

Answer (score 1):

```
Select Max(zCumuEnrolled) as Total From ZRecruitment 
where zDate Between '2010-05-01' AND '2010-05-30'
```

If I get you, somewhat confusing question. If you want Month and year of the record that has that maximum, you'll have to clarify.

PS how can a maximum be a total...

Comment: Well I was trying to group it by weeks, and one of the fields is cumulative people enrolled. So out of those 7 records(one each day) i only wanted to return one record and that is the total amount of people enrolled that week. Hope that clarifies some

Comment: Week??? what do you do with the bits at either end of the month? Put a bit of source data in the question, we are all guessing here.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
SELECT zCumuEnrolled, zDate
FROM vRecruitment  
Where zDate Between '2010-05-01' AND '2010-05-30' 
    AND zCumuEnrolled = (SELECT MAX(zCumuEnrolled) FROM vRecruitment)
```

Is this what you were looking to do?

Comment: Seems like it would be what I'm trying to do but when I run the query I get nothing....